# Find and Highlight Duplicates

Tags: vba, excel

Currently have an Excel document with a button named "Scan for Unassociated CC".

When I click on the button the following Module kicks off:

```
Sub scan()
Dim dataRange As Range
Dim oneCell As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Resource Info").Range("C:C"): Rem adjust
    Set dataRange = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

For Each oneCell In dataRange
    If 1 < Application.CountIf(dataRange, oneCell.Value) Then
        With oneCell
            .EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End With
    End If
Next oneCell
End Sub
```

This highlights all rows with a duplicate value in Column C.

Adding to this module, what is the best approach to only highlight rows with a duplicate value in Column C and Column K?

I'm new to VBA and learning. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Set a dataRange2 to the K column and use another COUNTIF and add the two together.

Comment: Since you're new to VBA: **A)** There's no reason for the `:` at the end of your `With` statement - that's the command separator and you don't have another executable statement on that line. **B)** Don't use `REM` for a comment - it's deprecated and makes you _look_ like a n00b ;) use a single quote `'` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @FreeMan!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub scan()
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim dataRange2 As Range
    Dim oneCell As Range
    Dim oneCell2 As Range
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Resource Info")
    WS.Cells.Interior.Color = -4142


    With WS.Range("C:C"): Rem adjust
        Set dataRange = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With

    Set dataRange2 = dataRange.Offset(0, 8)

    For Each oneCell In dataRange
        Set oneCell2 = oneCell.Offset(0, 8)
        If 1 < Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(dataRange, oneCell, dataRange2, oneCell2) Then
            With oneCell
                .EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End With
        End If
    Next oneCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @lbo - greatly appreciate the level of detail!